# How do I prevent other people from reading my python source code?

Tags: python, desktop-application

I'm just beginning my way through Python applications and was wondering about available packagers and how safe is the source code.

For example, is it easy for someone to unpack them?

Comment: What do you mean by packagers? If you've got a zip of python source code, you can unpack it and look at it. Running code you don't know what it does always has risks attached.

Comment: Hi Thom, 

I meant packagers like cx_Freeze, pyInstaller, py2exe, etc...

I'm just starting my way through programming and really like python because of all the available modules, however I know that it is not compiled, hence the above question.

Comment: ah, I'll bet source code can easily be extracted out of most of them.

Comment: Are there any other available methods for protecting it ?

Comment: I mainly write open source software, but a quick google search for "python obfuscator" should answer your questions.

Comment: What is your question by the way, "How do I prevent other people from reading my Python source code"?

Comment: It can be rephrased as you've noted above, however I don't have any experience with the packagers at all. I thought maybe they could be rated by level of security of code and wanted to know from developers experiences on stack overflow.

Comment: You can embed Python into a C/C++ program, then read your Python lines from an encrypted source. You will need to write some boilerplate code though.